# List all DOORS modules in Folder recursively via DXL and write to Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, recursion, ibm-doors

I hope that someone can help me with this one:
(I've previously searched if other questions could fit...)

I'm trying to list all DOORS modules in a specific directory with a recursive DXL function and write the module names (full path/name) to an excel sheet

This is what i got until now...the problem seems to be that "z" is reset to 1 again

In Excel VBA i call the DXL script like this (works):

```
objDoorsApp.runStr ("#include <" & sInterface & ">;;createFolderNameForRecursion ()")
```

It calls a function to initially call the recursive function: (works too)

```
void createFolderNameForRecursion()
{
int z = 1
WriteAllModulesRecursively2ExistExcel(folder("/00_Platform/30Software/30_Basis_SW/IoStck"), z);
}
```

Here's the recursive function:

```
void WriteAllModulesRecursively2ExistExcel(Folder f, int z) 
{
Item i
Module m
string ausgabe,temp
OleAutoObj  objExcel = oleGetAutoObject("Excel.Application")
OleAutoObj  objBook
OleAutoObj  objSheet = null
OleAutoArgs oleArgs = create
Object  oCur
Module  mCur
bool    excelVisible 
string  sTemp = ""
string  sResult = ""
//int   iRow = 1
string sBookName = "PP_Tst_IT_Report_Template.xls"
string sSheetName = "Delivery"
string result = ""

/* Make Excel visible to the user */
oleGet(objExcel, "Visible", excelVisible) 
if (!excelVisible) olePut(objExcel,"visible",true)

/* Get workbook */
sResult = oleGet(objExcel,"Workbooks", sBookName)

/* Get a handle on Sheet 1 in active workbook */
clear oleArgs
put(oleArgs, sSheetName) 
sResult = oleGet(objExcel, "Sheets", oleArgs, objSheet)

for i in f do 
{

    if (type(i)=="Folder" || type(i) =="Project") {  WriteAllModulesRecursively2ExistExcel(folder(i), z) }
    if (type(i)=="Formal")
    {
        sTemp = fullName i
        if (sTemp!=null)
        {       

            result = z " --> " fullName i "\n"

            objCell = ExcelGetCell(objSheet, z, 1)
            olePut(objCell,"Value",result)

            z++
        }
    } 
}
oleCloseAutoObject (objExcel)
}
```

Like i said "z" is reset to 1 if the "end" of a folder is reached.
What can I do about it? Is there any way?

If i just say

```
print fullName i "\n"
```

it works...but i need the module names in an excel sheet

Comment: Hey, thanks for the code snippet -- very useful example of how to access an existing workbook and worksheet by their names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try moving the `int z = 1` outside your function. If it is in the outer layer of the script it will be global. You won't need to pass it into the functions, and it should not get reset.

Example:

```
int z = 1

void WriteAllModulesRecursively2ExistExcel(Folder f)
{
  // do something
  z++
}

void createFolderNameForRecursion() {
  WriteAllModulesRecursively2ExistExcel(YOUR_FOLDER)
}
```

Good Luck!